# Set text caption in an InputSelect containing Enum values

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

How to set the text caption in an InputSelect component containing values extracted from an Enum object,
and how to validate that a value has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code sample describes how to use enum with the InputSelect built-in component, how to add a placeholder, and how to use the Required attribute to ensure that the user has selected a value before saving the form data.

```
@page "/"

@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<EditForm EditContext="@EditContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" 
                                                      Context="NewContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Enter your Name: </label>
        <InputText Id="name" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="@comment.Name"> 
        </InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => comment.Name)" />

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Select your country: </label>
    <InputSelect ValueExpression="@(() => comment.Country)"
         Value="@comment.Country" ValueChanged="@((Country? args) => 
                                                comment.Country = args)">
        <option value="">Select country...</option>
        @foreach (var country in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Country)))
        {
            <option value="@country">@country</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => comment.Country)" />
    </div>

    <p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
</EditForm>


@code
    {
     
    private EditContext EditContext;
    private Comment comment = new Comment();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Submitting");
    }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EditContext = new EditContext(comment);
    
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
    
    public enum Country
    {
        USA,
        Britain,
        Germany,
        Israel

    }
    public class Comment
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Country? Country { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Note: In order to enable validation of the InputSelect component above, whether you leave the first option empty or add label text, you have to make the Country property nullable. Note that the first option may have a numeric value as 0 or -1
(like Angular if you wish) or any number for that matter. It does not matter what the value is. you can use the string Select or empty string or even not use the value attribute at all. It still works. It's because the check is done against the enum's members, and if a value, that is the value of the first option is not
part of the enum, the validation is triggered. Thus the enum itself can start from 0 or from 1 as done here, or from any other number.